# FastAi LSTM forward method issue

Tags: lstm, fast-ai

Trying to create a simple LSTM model and work with FastAI framework but failed.

```
class SimpleLSTM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_dim, output_dim, bs):
        super().__init__()
        self.input_dim = input_dim
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        self.bs = bs

        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(self.input_dim, self.hidden_dim)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(self.hidden_dim, self.output_dim)

    def forward(self, *inputs):
        print(f'in[0]: {inputs[0].shape}')
        out, self.h = self.lstm(inputs[0].view(1, self.bs, self.input_dim))
        y_pred = self.linear(out)
        return y_pred[-1]
```

This module works when I feed the raw data to the model, but it failed when I initialize it with Learner module.

It complaints that the shape of data is wrong. Here the full code

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import pandas as pd
import fastai
from fastai.tabular import *

size = 200
bs = 20
X = torch.randn(size, 5)
y = (X.T[0] * 1.2 + X.T[1] * 4.2 + X.T[2] * 0.56 + X.T[3] * 0.12 + X.T[4] * 7.2 + torch.randn(size)).view(size, 1)
valid_ratio = 0.2
valid_samples = int(valid_ratio * size)
print(f'X.shape: {X.shape}')
print(f'y.shape: {y.shape}')
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(X.data.numpy()), pd.DataFrame(y.data.numpy())], axis=1)
df.columns = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'y']

class SimpleLSTM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_dim, output_dim, bs):
        super().__init__()
        self.input_dim = input_dim
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        self.bs = bs

        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(self.input_dim, self.hidden_dim)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(self.hidden_dim, self.output_dim)

    def forward(self, *inputs):
        print(f'in[0]: {inputs[0].shape}')
        out, self.h = self.lstm(inputs[0].view(1, self.bs, self.input_dim))
        y_pred = self.linear(out)
        return y_pred[-1]

model = SimpleLSTM(input_dim=5, hidden_dim=100, output_dim=1, bs=bs)
model

out = model(X[:bs])
print(f'out shape: {out.shape}')
out = model(X[:bs])
print(f'out shape: {out.shape}')

procs = [Normalize]
valid_idx = range(len(df)-valid_samples, len(df))
dep_var = 'y'
data = TabularDataBunch.from_df('.', df, dep_var, valid_idx=valid_idx, procs=procs, bs=bs)
learner = Learner(data, model)
learner.fit_one_cycle(1)
```

My observation is FastAI will feed two parameters one with shape (bs, ), another one with shape (bs, input_dim). Why does it pass the (bs, ) parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observation is correct, and what happens happens in the `collate_function` of your databunch. Basically, when iterating through a dataloader, what happens is that x is `data.collate_fn([data.train_ds.x[i] for i in list_indices)` where list_indices is the list of the indice of the sample you're using for this batch. 
When you look at `data.train_ds.x[0]`, you get

```
TabularLine d -0.4334; e 1.3458; a 0.4151; c 0.2837; b -0.6355;
```

and `data.train_ds.x[0].data` yields :

```
[tensor(0), tensor([-0.4334,  1.3458,  0.4151,  0.2837, -0.6355])]
```

The reason why this is yielded is that tabular data in fastai deals with categorical and continuous variable, and this is handled by creating a special learner with `tabular_learner`.

Two solutions are possible here :

- Modifying the dataset so that `data.train_ds.x[i].data` is a tensor of shape 5.
- Modifying the `collate_fn` so that it returns a (bs, input_dim) shaped tensor should do the trick as well.

For example, adding :

```
custom_collate_fn = lambda b: data_collate([(x.data[1], y) for (x, y) in b])
```

and passing `collate_fn=custom_collate_fn` in the databunch creation will work. However, you will get an error later because you have 200 items and your model only work if the batch is exaclty of size 64. Let me know if you need help on that matter.

Comment: I have changed bs to 20 to avoid the problem.

Comment: One more thing, how can I pass the time dimension to LSTM in this case? For example training 10 time steps at a time rather than just 1